# PhoneGap application that communicate with a remote DB

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sql, cordova

I build phoneGap app, its a facebook-style app, the idea of the is that users can post messages and their friends can comment on the message.
The app based on html, js and phoneGap.
I have a server with a mysql database.
My question is how can i pull and push a data from the remote DB.
I'm a begginer so I not really sure how to do this.
I need the page to be updated in real time, even after he finished loading

I Googled it and I realized I needed for that use Ajax, is that true?
Can anyone give me guidance?

Thanks :)

Sorry about my English..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two approaches:

- implement your own backend server that provides push, pull and notification services. This backend server talks to your database and provides services that are accessible from JavaScript (yes, probably using Ajax. Note that Ajax is a concept, and you will need to choose an implementation, such as the one provided by the jQuery/jqMobile frameworks). For speed and ease of use, consider a platform provider such as dotCloud.com, where you can leverage preconfigured servers and stay within the same programming language/environment (e.g. using Node.js and dotCloud's MySQL service).
- use a backend data server provided out of the box, such as parse.com or deployd.com. This not only gives you a ready framework and all the necessary interfaces for remote data storage and real time client updates, but also makes sure that your application will scale.

The first approach is better suited if you want to learn how to program a backend server, but it will leave you with the responsibility to make it secure and scalable.

The second approach seems more appropriate if you don't want to concern yourself with minute details on how to build and manage a backend server, but really concentrate on getting your app up and running.

BTW: I have no affiliation to any of the platforms or products mentioned, and simply include their names as examples. Other similar offerings might exist that maybe more appropriate or have less of a commercial backing.

EDIT: typos, correct domain names